# Edit datatype XML columns in Sqlplus

Tags: sql, xml

Need to edit specific value in an XML datatype column, like below

```
'<Dept>
<Dept_Emp>
<dept_id>10</dept_id>
<emp_name>Jack</emp_name>
<hire_date>2003-12-12T00:00:00</hire_date>
</Dept_Emp>
<Dept_Emp>
<dept_id>10</dept_id>
<emp_name>John</emp_name>
<hire_date>2007-03-11T00:00:00</hire_date>
</Dept_Emp>
<Dept_Emp>
<dept_id>10</dept_id>
<emp_name>Beth</emp_name>
<hire_date>2008-05-11T00:00:00</hire_date>
</Dept_Emp>
<Dept_Emp>
<dept_id>20</dept_id>
<emp_name>Mary</emp_name>
<hire_date>1999-01-03T00:00:00</hire_date>
</Dept_Emp>
<Dept_Emp>
<dept_id>20</dept_id>
<emp_name>Allen</emp_name>
<hire_date>2000-05-11T00:00:00</hire_date>
</Dept_Emp>
<Dept_Emp>
<dept_id>20</dept_id>
<emp_name>Diana</emp_name>
<hire_date>2001-09-09T00:00:00</hire_date>
</Dept_Emp>
<Dept_Emp>
<dept_id>20</dept_id>
<emp_name>Ramesh</emp_name>
<hire_date></hire_date>
</Dept_Emp>
</Dept>'
```

Using Sqlplus..
How can I edit. For example say I need to edit hire_date tag in this XML which is a column named Emp_Details in Employee table.`declare @new xml; select`

Please help, I have no clue what so ever on this so couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve it using the below statement.

update customer set xml = replace(xml,'OLD','NEW') where profile_name like '%DETAILS%' and lower(xml) like '%days%';